# Setting ConnectionTimeout for OdbcConnection (System.Data.Odbc) in c# does not work

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, timeout, odbc

I have a .net 4.0 c# application which needs an odbc connection to mssql 2008. The connection usually works perfect. But when I run a query which usually runs for some minutes (and no, at this point in the project I can't optimise the query runtime) I'll get a timeout after 30 seconds:

> ERROR [HYT00] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Query timeout
>   expired

I have already tried to change the driver (sqlsrv32.dll, sqlncli10.dll, sqlncli11.dll) for the odbc connection but I get always a similar error.

This is the dummy code I have built to simulate the problem:

```
using (
    OdbcConnection conn =
        new OdbcConnection("DSN=d3FA;uid=sa;pwd=1234;MARS_Connection=yes;Connection Timeout=37;"))
{
    conn.ConnectionTimeout = 37;
    conn.Open();

    OdbcCommand myCommand = new OdbcCommand("WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:45'", conn);
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

As you can see I have set the Connection Timeout in the connection string and I also set the property of the connection. But it seems that this information (37 seconds) is just ignored from the query execution. The timeout still occurs after 30 seconds.

From Microsoft I have the information that the Windows ODBC API offers the [SQLSetStmtAttr-Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712631%28VS.85%29.aspx) which would allow setting the SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT attribute. Perhaps setting this attribute would solve my problem - but I couldn't find any solution how I could set this value through .net.

Conclusion: Has anybody an idea how to increase the timeout value?

Comment: If your DB connection string is valid the connection timeout won't be applied since ODBC will connect to the DB. If you're expecting the command to generate the error, look at the CommandTimeout. This deals with a separate issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the CommandTimeout property of your OdbcCommand object like

```
myCommand.CommandTimeout=37;
```

Comment: aaaaahhhh...such a simple solution. Thank you fanisch that is exactly the right solution in my case!

Comment: doesn't help if the connection itself is hanging on open()

Comment: in the case that Open() hangs, how would the command ever get executed to be given a chance to timeout?

Comment: @CRice - the connection "hanging on open" is exactly what `ConnectionTimeout` is for. This Q&A is about a different situation. (Where OP was confused, and incorrectly used `ConnectionTimeout`, thinking this would affect his *query* timeout.)